# Pandas: what is plot in df.plot.bar()? Method or object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have seen df.plot(kind='bar') and df.plot.bar() in use. For the former, I would think plot is a method, using kind as a default parameter. For the latter, it seems that plot is an object.

So is 'plot' in df.plot an object or method?

Thanks!

Comment: A python object can also be callable if its class implements the `__call__` dunder method. So "method-like behavior" and "object-like behavior" are not mutually exclusive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A python object can also be callable if its class implements the `__call__` dunder method. So "method-like behavior" and "object-like behavior" are not mutually exclusive:

```py
class TwoNumberOperation:
    
    def __init__(self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        
    def addition(self):
        
        return self(what="add")
    
    def multiplication(self):
        
        return self(what="mult")
    
    def __call__(self, what="add"): 
        
        if what == "add":
            return self.x1 + self.x2
        elif what == "mult":
            return self.x1 * self.x2
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"{what} is not a valid operation")


two_n = TwoNumberOperation(1, 2)
```

Now we can call this instance either directly

```
two_n(what="mult")
# output: 2
```

or by calling the `addition` method explicitly:

```
two_n.addition()
# output:  3
```

**Now to pandas**:

If we look at the source code, the plotting attributes are added to the `DataFrame` class [(link)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/70352c2a23ba1785fe6682ac41ffe26f88eb27ee/pandas/core/frame.py#L446) at the very end:

```
class DataFrame(NDFrame):
    ...

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Add plotting methods to DataFrame
    plot = CachedAccessor("plot", pandas.plotting.PlotAccessor)
    ...
```

The `pandas.plotting.PlotAccessor` defines most plotting methods which are available in the DataFrame class, including `.line` ([link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/059c8bac51e47d6eaaa3e36d6a293a22312925e6/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1032)), `.bar` ([link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/059c8bac51e47d6eaaa3e36d6a293a22312925e6/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1119)) etc.

Its `__call__` method ([link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/059c8bac51e47d6eaaa3e36d6a293a22312925e6/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L890)) does some data manipulation and forwards the data to the plot backend. It takes a `kind=` parameter (which is actually why you can do `df.plot(kind="bar")` instead of `df.plot.bar()`).

Similar to the `TwoNumberOperation` example above, the methods `pd.Dataframe.plot.bar` etc. call the `PlotAccessor.__call__` method under the hood, so `df.line` is really just ([link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/059c8bac51e47d6eaaa3e36d6a293a22312925e6/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1032))

```
    def line(self, x=None, y=None, **kwargs):

        return self(kind="line", x=x, y=y, **kwargs)
```

All the magic happens in the `__call__` method!

Comment: why using `plot = CachedAccessor("plot", pandas.plotting.PlotAccessor)` but not `plot = pandas.plotting.PlotAccessor(self)`